# mmap invalid argument - reading multiple files from command line and writing to one output file

Tags: c, file, mmap, read-write

I am writing a C program that takes more than one file from the command line and combines them into one output file. If the output file is not given, it is created. I copy the file content by using mmap.

However, when I run the following code, I get "mmap: invalid argument" and I am not sure why.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <sys/mman.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  int opt, output=0, len; 
  int fd_o, fd_i;
  char *addr=NULL;
  struct stat stat_input;
  const char *errmsg="Invalid argument:\n";
  const char *usage=
      "combine to one\n";

  while((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "o"))!= -1) {
      switch(opt){
      case 'o': 
        output=1;
        fd_o=open(argv[argc-1], O_WRONLY|O_CREAT|O_TRUNC, 0644);
        if (fd_o == -1){
          perror("open");
          exit(1);
        }
        break;
      case '?':
        write(2, errmsg, strlen(errmsg));
        write(2, usage, strlen(usage));
        exit(1);
    }
  }

  if (output==0){
    write(2, errmsg, strlen(errmsg));
    write(2, usage, strlen(usage));
    exit(1);
  }
 
  for(; optind < argc; optind++){
    fd_i=open(argv[optind], O_RDONLY);
    if (fd_i == -1){
      perror("open");
      exit(1);
}

    fstat(fd_i, &stat_input);
    len=stat_input.st_size;
    addr=mmap(0, len, PROT_READ, MAP_SHARED, fd_i, 0);
    if (addr == MAP_FAILED) {
      close(fd_i);
      perror("mmap");
      exit(1);
    }
    write(fd_o, *addr, len);
    close(fd_i);
    munmap(addr,len);
  }
  close(fd_o);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem is actually your option parsing.  As it stands, you always use the last argument as the output file if `-o` is specified at all.  So if you run `./myprog f1 f2 -o out`, then all of `f1, f2, out` will be used as input files.  And if you run `./myprog -o out f1 f2` then all of `out, f1, f2` will be inputs, and output will go to `f2`.

I presume you didn't expect to use the output file as input, and if it's empty, you will attempt to create a map of length 0, which will fail with "Invalid argument".  My guess is this is the cause of your problem.

The correct way to use `getopt` to process an option with an argument is to use `"o:"` as the option string, and then when `getopt` returns `'o'`, the variable `optarg` will point to the option's argument; that's what you should use as your output filename instead of `argv[argc-1]`.

A couple other bugs:

- `write(fd_o, *addr, len);` should be `write(fd_o, addr, len);` since `write` expects a pointer to its data.  You should get a compiler warning about this.
- You'll want to test for `len != 0` before calling `mmap` in case someone really does run the program on an empty input file.
- I'm not sure why you're using `write()` for your usage message instead of just `fprintf(stderr, ...)`.  If for some reason stdio functions are not acceptable (even though you seem to have no problem with `perror()` elsewhere), then the standard function `dprintf` may make your life a bit easier.

Answer (score 0):

From man page [mmap()](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html)

```
void *mmap(void *addr, size_t length, int prot, int flags, int fd, off_t offset);
```

Possible reasons for EINVAL (Invalid argument error) :

```
    1) We don't like addr, length, or offset (e.g., they are too large, or not aligned on a page boundary).

    2) (since Linux 2.6.12) length was 0.

    3) flags contained none of MAP_PRIVATE, MAP_SHARED or MAP_SHARED_VALIDATE.
```

I think `len` in `len = stat_input.st_size;` is zero. This might be the reason.